# How to access the data in a data frame by its header in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, dataframe

I have a file with the extension `XLS`. When I open it in `Excel`, it has columns with headers. I want to get the numeric data in each column in Matlab by its header. For example, when I try data('y') I get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use [xlsread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html):

```
[data, header] = xlsread('myfilelocation','sheetname');
```

`sheetname` can be skipped, i.e. `xlsread('myfilelocation')`, if the xls file contains only one sheet or it is the first sheet you want to read from.

Then you can search for headers

```
myHeaders = {'X','Y','Z'};
for i = 1:numel(myHeaders)
    data(:,i) = data(:,strcmp(header, myHeaders{i}));
end
```

Note that the second output from `xlsread` is not necessarily the header but all non-numeric data; if your xls sheet does contain some other than header texts,  `header(1,:)` should be used to extract header texts.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to use [readtable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), as the function automatically detects the headers for you.

Read the table and store in Table T:

```
T = readtable('yourfile.xls');
```

Then simply use dot notation to access your data. For example, to access the data contained in the first column you can simply use the name of the header (e.g. *FirstColumnHeader*):

```
DataFirstColumn = T.FirstColumnHeader
```

Comment: Note that if the name of the header is stored in a variable as a string (i.e. `header = 'y';`), you will have to use [curly brace indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) like so: `T{:, header}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo code,

```
filename = %name of the file;
delimiter = {','}; %it's comma separated, can be changed
startRow = 3;
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
formatSpec = '%f%f[^\n\r]'; %reading first two column only. can be changed.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType','string', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine','\r\n');
fclose(fileID);
```